# How to set a app launch url as a page of third party website in google apps marketplace manifest.json file

Tags: json, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, manifest.json

How to set the app launch url as mentioned in below ( for eg i mentioned google.com) third party website. when we mentioned like this and upload this file in google apps marketplace dashboard it show this error,

"This hosted web app specifies one or more URLs that are not matched by sites you own. If this app will be published for anyone to access, you must verify ownership of or association to sites to match all of the URLs listed below.

Unmatched web_url:
http://www.google.com
To verify your ownership of these websites, add the necessary websites using Google Webmaster Tools and return here to complete this step.

If the site already has an owner, you may request they grant you an association which allows you to publish apps and extensions to the Chrome Web Store on behalf of the site. You may request an association in the verified website section below."

{

"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "mfnksj",

"version": "0.0.0.1",

"icons": {

```
"128": "icons/128x128-icon.png",
"16": "icons/16x16-icon.png"
```

},

"container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],

"api_console_project_id": "339735456282",

"app" : {

```
"launch" : {
  "web_url" : "http://www.google.com"
}
```

}

}

So please help me to set redirect url once app icon clicked.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Manifest File](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#manifest_file) in the **Publishing Your App** guide:

> The `web_url` string in the app section of the manifest defines the
>   actual URL used to launch your app.

Looking at your manifest, you seem to have indicated that you own www.google.com.
Change that to the url path of your web app.

Comment: I just mentioned googl.com as example. I need to redirect to a login page of a website that i haven't owned. How to just redirect to some other website which is not own by me?